# Proper usage of "since" and "from" with regard to duration of time

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> When you returned, I had been at home since 10 minutes.

> When you returned, I had been at home from 5 minutes.

In such sentences, is it correct to use *since* or *from*? When *since* is used?

Comment: tips: `since`,
I am waiting since morning. and I am waiting for morning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is an area which often gives difficulty between English and other European languages.

- over a period: "for", 
  "I have been working for two hours"
  (In some cases you can omit the 'for', eg "I have been waiting two hours")
- from a point: "since":
  "I have been working since 12"

"From" is unusual here: I think it is only used to give emphasis to the starting point, and notice that it would take a simple past continous, not a perfect continuous:
"I was waiting here from 12 o'clock!"

A difficulty that French and German speakers often have is that they want to say "I am here since ... ", which is never idiomatic in English. There is one instance of this that actually does cause confusion some times: when an English speaker asks "How long are you here?" they are asking about the future, but a French or German speaker will often misunderstand that as about the past (i.e. "How long have you been here?").

Comment: +1 Note that English speakers also use *in* in some constructions: "It's the coldest winter in eight years."

Answer (score 18):

Both are wrong. You use *since* when talking about a specific point in time. (I suppose you could use *from* in this case as well, but I haven't seen it in actual American usage.) For example:

> When you returned, I had been home since 3:00.

When talking about a duration, *for* is used:

> When you returned, I had been home for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Both seem awkward.

I would write

> When you returned I had been home for 10 minutes.

Comment: If OP's native language is Italian, I guess the misunderstanding might stem from there. (Spanish, relatively close to Italian, at least has a construct like "desde hace 10 minutos", literally "since 10 minutes ago"...)

Comment: @Jonik: My first language is Italian. In Italian we say _quando sei tornato, ero a casa da 10 minuti_; _da_ can be translated with both _since_, or _from_, and that is the reason I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I won't say *since* and *from* in the example sentence provided because *since* indicates a point of time, whereas *from* denotes time from starting to end. Let's see in this example:

> I have not seen her *since* morning.
>
> Boys play cricket *from* 4pm to 6pm every sunday.

Rather, I would use *for* in the sentence which is used to show a length of time.

> When you returned, I had been at home *for* 5 minutes.