# Is there a difference in meaning between "from the beginning" and "since the beginning"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases

> He’s been with us **from** the beginning.

Is there a difference between *from* and *since* in the context of the quoted sentence?

Comment: To me, there's no difference in meaning.

Comment: Possible duplicate (although your example is better): _[Proper usage of “since” and “from” with regard to duration of time](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1358/5822)_.

Comment: To me from the beginning sounds more formal than since the beginning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think *from the beginning* puts a little more emphasis and focus on the significance of the *beginning*. If you were talking about a business, perhaps "he" was there in the planning process and integral to starting the business. *Since the beginning* places more emphasis on the intervening time period. Again, if a business, perhaps "he" is the most loyal employee who was hired early on—the focus being more on the amount of time that has passed.

Beyond this, if you use the blockquoted form you'll be in better [company](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+the+beginning%2Csince+the+beginning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's watch the movie again from the beginning. (NOT since the beginning)

I have been working on this project since the beginning.

I have been working on this project from the beginning.

Comment: This is not very helpful to someone to whom the differences are not obvious. You should elaborate on this.