# What’s the difference between "I have known her since/for a long time"?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositional-phrases

What’s the difference between these two:

1. I have known her **for** a long time.
2. I have known her **since** a long time.

I think that the first one says that we have been friends for a long time but we broke our friendship recently, but that the second one says that we have been friends since a long time and our friendship still continues?

Is this accurate?

Comment: What about the first sentence indicates to you that the friendship has been broken?

Comment: The second sentence is unacceptable.

Comment: The first sentence is grammatical and indicates nothing about breaking or even having friendship; only acquaintance. The second sentence is ungrammatical and therefore means nothing, because _since_ requires a object noun phrase referring to some point of time in the past, not a length of time.

Comment: But answered at [Proper usage of “since” and “from” with regard to duration of time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time). (Colin Fine's answer)

Answer (score 0):

The first statement show the propinquity between the speaker and the second person (party).
The second statement shows the identification of the object (person) in the sentence, it could rely on the character, ideology, and personality of the person, which there is no or less relationship affinity.

Comment: Why *propinquity* rather than the more common *proximity* or the even better *closeness* or *distance*? Also, "since a long time" is ungrammatical in English.

Comment: I don't think using the word propinquity in that sentence is wrong, what do you mean?                     Is it because using "since and longtime" in the sentence forms tautology?

Comment: Okay, concerning the question, "since and long time" in the sentence, could it be called tautology?

Comment: I just came across that word that's why I used it

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler wrote in a comment:

> The first sentence is grammatical and indicates nothing about breaking or even having friendship; only acquaintance. The second sentence is ungrammatical and therefore means nothing, because *since* requires a object noun phrase referring to some point of time in the past, not a length of time.