# Which one is correct? "I am suffering from fever since yesterday" or "I am suffering from fever from yesterday"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, time, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

I am not good in English literature.

From daily use of English language, it seems to me that the second *from* in:

> 1 I am suffering from fever **from** yesterday

is the correct word. But, my friend, a major in English, is saying that the correct word is *since*:

> 2. I am suffering from fever **since** yesterday.

I do not understand why he says that I must use *since* not *from*. Can anyone explain which version is right and why?

I am asking for the situation when using the present continuous construction: *be* + *VERBing*. I do not mean the present perfect continuous.

#### More explanation

I know that in the case of **present *perfect* continuous** case we can use *since, for, from*. However, in a sentence of **present continuous** structure, then what should we write, *from* or *since*?  Please explain the grammatical law that forbid me from using *from*.

Comment: Hello and welcome, Tarit, In fact, in American English the most idiomatic and common way to express this is *I have been suffering from (a) fever **since** yesterday*, or simply *I have had a fever **since** yesterday*.

Comment: @Knotell Thank you, Can you explain why grammatically it is the correct way?

Comment: Tarit, your question is a **duplicate** of the question [Proper usage of “since” and “from” with regard to duration of time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time) and [other questions already asked on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=from+since). Please read those questions and answers, and consult internet grammar sites that explain the issue; and then if you are still confused, feel free to edit your question and tell us why the explanations were not sufficient.

Comment: Would second "_I have had a fever since yesterday_" as the more idiomatic way of saying this in my Br.E experience. To me, you suffer _from_ a disease, which may cause you to _have_ symptoms (such as a fever).

Comment: @TripeHound I know that, but if I use 'am' , then how we have 'since' ? Can you explain why grammatically it is correct?

Comment: @Knotell I am asking for *present continuous* case.

Comment: @taritgoswami You do not understand: you cannot say that in English. You cannot use "I am suffering from/since" anything because it has to be a perfect "I **have been** suffering since". So what you are asking for is not permitted; it is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to say this would be to use present perfect instead of present continuous, but with *since* as the preposition:

> I have been suffering from [a] fever since yesterday.

Comment: As the OP said in my comment, he/ she wants specifically in the continuous tense

Comment: So OP is asking specifically for a non-idiomatic answer? I doubt that.

Comment: Oh, it's my bad. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ELU!

I believe that "since" is grammatically correct.

"From" is usually for **places**. For example, "I come from the United States."

"Since" is usually for **reasons** or **starting points of time**. For example, "Since we've got a few minutes to wait for the train, let's have a cup of coffee." (Reason) (Cambridge Dictionary)

Back to your question. "Yesterday" is the **starting point** of "your suffering from fever". Therefore, you should use "Since".

Hope it helps!

Comment: P.S.: You can search if there are any existing questions that can answer your question, to avoid duplicates. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I am mainly asking for the case when the sentence is in *present continuous*.

Answer (score 0):

When you have no conformation  for time and date therefore  you should write "from" when you are confirmed  then write "since "

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You may want to look up usage of "from" and "since", as your answer is not clear. There are issues with the tense of the sentence as well, and one really doesn't use either "from" or "since" with the present tense in this particular context.

Answer (score -1):

"I have been suffering from fever since yesterday "
But we use since for point of time .(కచ్చితమైన కాలము like since evening ,since Sunday ,since "4 "O clock ect.
So We should use since before yesterday  .

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Since we welcome your input, please take a moment to take a tour of the site.